# Console Log Returning HTML Page Text Instead of JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to return a model in JSON form from a request sent as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        (function(){
            console.log("ran");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://clas.uconn.edu/Employees/Edit/22",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Success: " + data);
                    empData = data;
                }
           });
       })();
    });
```

My Controller for this method is:

```
// GET: Employees/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        var id = employee.id;
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return new JsonResult() { Data = employee, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
```

However I am getting an entire html page in the consol log even though none of these controller actions return a view. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
After adding the datatype, I am getting an error in the console log saying:

```
GET http://localhost:59909/Employees/EmployeeLookupDisplay   
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Which part of your action controller is hit? As far I know, HttpNotFound() will return entire HTML page.

Comment: Is your controller action success?

Comment: What is on that html page received from the MVC controller, usually errors come through, yellow screen of death, so use chrome dev tools or something to render that page (click preview)

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the entire page because there is an error in your request somewhere.

Add a block error to your ajax call and `console.log` on the `xhr.` You will get much more information about the error like this.

What you can try is making the request on POST and checking the properties of the context on the C# code. Sometimes adding `dataType` and the encoding helps for the request.

Additionally check for the returning status of your request on your browser developer tools. In chrome it is the network tab that shows all requests and their status.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, but according to your code its always returning HTTP not foud which is HTML page. if you have data to employee. i mean your controller action getting success without any error. then you can try tis.

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://clas.uconn.edu/Employees/Edit/22",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Success: " + data);
                empData = data;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of returning `new JsonResult() { Data = employee, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };`, just `return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);'`

Another thing i see:

on the first line you are doing `var id = employee.id;` -> where `employee` comes from? maybe the error is there.